# How to initialize Java UDFs in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

My driver script is written in PySpark, where I do some complex transformations on columns. The transformations have been implemented as Java UDFs for performance reasons.

In my PySpark code, I register the Java UDF using :

```
session.udf.registerJavaFunction("my_udf", "com.example.MyUDF", StringType())
```

I am able to execute the transformation in PySpark as follows :

```
output_df = input_df.withColumn(f"transformed", F.expr("my_udf(col1, col2)"))
```

My Java UDF is defined as follows :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF2;

public class MyUDF implements UDF2<Integer, Integer, String> {

  @Override
  public String call(Integer x, Integer y) {
       // Do something ...
  }
}
```

Now, the transformation defined by `MyUDF` requires some other data as inputs. E.g. let's say there is a map of values against which lookup needs to be performed, and the output is the sum of the mapped values, i.e.

```
  public String call(Integer x, Integer y) {
       // Pseudocode
       return myMap.get(x) + myMap.get(y);
  }
```

Question: What is a good way to read the `myMap` from a database and make it available to the UDF written in Java?

I have read that broadcast variables are meant for such purposes, but I need help in understanding how I can access any broadcast variable created in PySpark from the Java UDF? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1. Declare your map as final and call it from your udf:

   ```
   final HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
   public String call(Integer x, Integer y) {
        // Pseudocode
        return myMap.get(x) + myMap.get(y);
   }
   ```
2. But a better solution is to use broadcast variable and then call it
   from you udf:

   ```
   HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
   Broadcast<HashMap<String, String>> myMapBroadcast = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext()).broadcast(myMap);
   public String call(Integer x, Integer y) {
        // Pseudocode
        HashMap<String, String> myMap2 = myMapBroadcast.value();
        return myMap2.get(x) + myMap2.get(y);
   }
   ```